# javascript not displaying login form again

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I click on the log in button the pop up open correctly. But when I close it and again click on the log in button without refreshing the page, it doesn't appear.

my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

load_login_page = function() {
    $.get(HOST_NAME + "e_commerce/ECommerces/ecommerce_login", {}, function(data) {
        $("#temp_login_box").html(data);
        $.blockUI({
            message:$('#temp_login_box'),
            css:{
                top:($(window).height() - 300) / 2 + 'px',
                left:($(window).width() - 800) / 2 + 'px',
                width:'620px',
                border:'none',
                background:'none',
                cursor:'default'
            },
            overlayCSS:{ backgroundColor:'#333' }
        });
        load_login_ajax_form();
    });
};

load_login_ajax_form = function () {
    var options = {
        beforeSubmit:show_login_request, // pre-submit callback
        success:show_login_response  // post-submit callback
    };
    $('#product_info_form').ajaxForm(options);

};

show_login_request = function (formData, jqForm, options) {
    return true;
};

show_login_response = function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    if (responseText == 'ok') {
        //  $("#temp_login_box").html(responseText);
        window.location.href = HOST_NAME + "e_commerce/ECommerces/user_desboard";
        //load_login_ajax_form();
    } else {
        $("#temp_login_box").html(responseText);
        load_login_ajax_form();
    }
};

hide_login_info = function() {
    $.unblockUI();

};
```

hide_login_info is form closing function. temp_login_box is id to targeted div. please help me out with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please trace your function `load_login_page` to check whether `$.get` called every time.

because you are creating `$.blockUI` in success of $.get

Comment: call `hide_login_info` function before you create.
for example:


load_login_page = function() {
    $.get(HOST_NAME + "e_commerce/ECommerces/ecommerce_login", {}, function(data) {
`hide_login_info();`
        $("#temp_login_box").html(data);

Answer (score 1):

To check more i need $.unblockUI Code.

But what i suggest is, in unblockUI function either you do empty the div or hide it.

- If you hide it then to show on click you have to write $().show(); in $.blockUI function

if it is not the reason 
provide $.unblockUI code then might be i can help you.
Note  is jquery selector for the div you hide

Comment: In you code in last 3 line hide_login_info = function() {
    $.unblockUI();

}; what is that?

Comment: I wanna know what it is doing when it is closing the pop up form , as it might be , what i suggested in my answer.